# How to check policies for objects created through AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my program one `Board` can have many `Sections`. On `Boards#show` I list all `Sections` for this `Board`. A user can create, edit and delete `Sections` for `Boards` this user has created. 
I use Pundit for my authorizations.

My problem is that after having added AJAX to the create `Section` action, my policy checks don't work anymore. The AJAX call is working fine in that `Sections` are added but the "Edit" and "Delete" links are only displayed after I reload the page.

### Boards#show

```
<% if policy(@board).edit? %>
<p><strong>Create a new Section</strong></p>
  <%= render 'sections/shared/form', board: @board, section: @section %>
<% end %>
<br>

<p><strong>Sections</strong></p>
<div id="sections">
  <% @board.sections.order(id: :asc).each_with_index do |section, index| %>
    <span><%= "#{index + 1}. #{section.title}" %></span>
    <% if policy(section).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_board_section_path(@board, @board.sections[index]) %>
    <% end %>
    <% if policy(section).destroy? %>
      <%= link_to("Delete", board_section_path(@board, @board.sections[index]), method: :delete) %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

### Form partial

```
<%= simple_form_for([@board, @section], remote: true, authenticity_token: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, id: "section_title" %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

### AJAX call

```
var newSection = "<span><%= "#{@board.sections.length}. #{@section.title}" %></span><br>";

var sections = document.getElementById('sections');
sections.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newSection);

var sectionTitle = document.getElementById('section_title');
sectionTitle.value = '';
```

I think the problem is that the newly created `Section` isn't inserted into the loop and thus the policy cannot be checked. How could I refactor my code to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to render you HTML templates into your `js.erb` file. See the post from the DHH https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3697-server-generated-javascript-responses how to use this properly. It is an older post so maybe some things changed but you should know what to search for. But if it still works this way, you should be able to do something like this:

Extract section to a partial `_section.html.erb`

```html
    <span><%= "#{index + 1}. #{section.title}" %></span>
    <% if policy(section).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_board_section_path(@board, @board.sections[index]) %>
    <% end %>
    <% if policy(section).destroy? %>
      <%= link_to("Delete", board_section_path(@board, @board.sections[index]), method: :delete) %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
```

Use this partial also in your `Boards#show` file.

Render your partial in the `js.erb` file

```
var newSection = "<span><%=j render @section %></span><br>";
```

Something like this should work, but I don't use server generated javascripts so they could have changed some things. But hopefully it will help you at least with the direction.

Comment: Thanks @edariedl, this worked like a charm! Why do we `render @section` in the `js.erb` file though as opposed to `render sections/section`?

Comment: @newkidontheblock `render @section` is just a shorthand for something like this `render partial: 'section/section', locals: { section: @section }`. It is easier to write, but it is more magical. It is up to you which one of these you would like to use. Look at the documentation for partial rendering to find really nice overview of all the ways you can use to render partials https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html